# Java create directories and delete files which should be directories

Tags: java, file, directory, delete-file, mkdirs

I want to create a directory path in Java using the `File#mkdirs()` method. Let's consider the path `"example/example/example"`. `new File("example/example/example").mkdirs()` creates the directories. However, if `new File("example/example").exists() && new File("example/example").isFile()` invoking `new File("example/example/example").mkdirs()` does nothing and returns `false`. If (and only if) this case happens, I want that the file gets deleted and the directory path is created instead. Is there any solution to this problem or do I have to handle it by myself (iterating through the path)?

Comment: No. Elbow grease.

Comment: If you’re asking whether there is a single method that will obliterate an existing file and replacing it with a directory, the answer is no.  You will need to move or remove it yourself.

Comment: And you still probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: @chrylis I think I probably know what you mean but can you please explain it a bit more in detail what exactly I shouldn't do and why?

Also note that if someone creates a correct answer, stating that it's not possible with a single method, providing an example code how it would be possible and explaining why I shouldn't do it or why it's bad, I would accept the answer.

Comment: Just going around deleting files is very likely to erase something important. It's much more usual to fail with an error message and let the user do that.